# joining multiple tables using foreign keys

Tags: mysql, one-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

```
Select Company.Company_ID, Company.Company_name, Users.Users_ID, Users.User_Name, Ratings.Rating_ID,      Ratings.Comments, Ratings.Reliability, Ratings.Rating
from company
join UserCompJobRating on Users.Users_ID = UserCompJobRating.Users_ID
join Company_job on UserCompJobRating.Comp_job_ID = Company_job.Comp_job_ID
join Ratings on UserCompJobRating.Rating_ID = Ratings.Ratings_ID;
```

Hi again.  I dont seem to be able to get my head around these joins carry on at the moment.  here i am tryin to create a many to many to many i guess would be the best way to describe it.

I have a Company table, a Users Table, a Ratings table and a Jobs table.

Each company can perform various job types

Each user can rate a job style performed and leave a comment etc

each job Type can have many comments, as they are not user specific (at present)

I have a small table called UserCompJobRating which i assumed would help join these tables together to perform this query, but i am having difficulty piecing this together.

This table has a UCJR_ID (primary Key), a Comp_Job_ID, a Users_ID and a Rating_ID.  these are all foreign keys

I also have a table called Company_Job which links the company to the spcific job type it described.

Im trying to use this joining table (so to speak) to allow me to create this join so that i can display the select clause

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: how would i join these so that i can view the items in the select statement